# Python Array index is out of range but works after printing

Tags: python, arrays

Here is my code:

```
pixel = pixels[pixel_position * pixel_byte_width :(pixel_position + 1) * pixel_byte_width]
r = pixel[0]
g = pixel[1]
b = pixel[2]
```

Here is the error:

```
line 25, in wr
g = pixel[1]
IndexError: array index out of range
```

Now let's say I do this to my code:

```
pixel = pixels[pixel_position * pixel_byte_width :(pixel_position + 1) * pixel_byte_width]
print(pixel)
r = pixel[0]
g = pixel[1]
b = pixel[2]
```

Prints pixel but ultimately slows down the code... What is going on? No error after printing and it prints the full thing. Doing `len(pixel)` always prints 3. Any ideas? Thanks!

EDIT:
I am using python 3+

Comment: What is the minimum value `pixel_byte_width` can take?

Comment: Does this happen consistently? Since it's calculation based, something you didn't notice might have changed.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye the minimum is 3... it's four if the image has transparency. I don't need to check though because it has a metadata value to tell me.

Comment: @MoonCheesez It happens every time. The only way to make it work is to delay right before the place of the error, but I need it fast because otherwise it takes ages to complete (as in many hours).

Comment: I am still waiting for input from anyone, please get back to me soon!

Comment: I suggest wrapping a `try` block around the place the exception is happening and trying to print values like `pixel` and `pixel_position` in the `except`. It doesn't make much sense that the error only occurs when you don't `print` the list first, so perhaps you can figure out what's causing the error by letting it happen and printing afterwards. Oh, one more question: Is `pixels` an ordinary list, or some other container type (like a `numpy` array)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain about how that `array` object requires its indexing, but you can avoid indexing by unpacking your values directly from the array:

```
r, g, b = pixel
```

If it does contain three elements, you're sure to have your values without any errors.

Comment: It didn't seem to work. It says that it expected 3 but got 1. Also it seems to not be the first one.

Comment: Means `pixel` does not contain three elements always as you suggest

Comment: The weird part is it does... if I print it it clearly shows three values in every one... I looked through a ton of pixels